# How to declare the elements of an array non-nullable?

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, database-design, sql-null

In the following simple table

```sql
CREATE TABLE foo (
  things VARCHAR ARRAY
);
```

It's possible to insert `null` as an element of `things`:

```sql
INSERT INTO foo VALUES ('{"hi", null, "ho"}');
```

But I'd like to not allow this.

Changing the definition to the following, however,

```sql
CREATE TABLE foo (
  things VARCHAR ARRAY NOT NULL
);
```

Only prevents this

```sql
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (null);
```

which is not what I want. (I still want to allow that.)

So how can I declare not the column, but the elements of the array column to be non-nullable?

Comment: Since "non-nullable" is a tecnical term with a meaning already, don't use it for anything else, like whatever it is you mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a check constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE foo 
(
  things text[], 
  constraint check_things_not_null 
    check ( cardinality(things) = cardinality(array_remove(things, null)))
);
```

alternatively you can use `array_position()`

```
CREATE TABLE foo 
(
  things text[], 
  constraint check_things_not_null 
    check ( array_position(things, null) is null)
);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `check` with `array_position()` as following

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  things text[] NOT NULL check (array_position(things, null) is null)
);
```

and you can also check for empty array

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  things text[] NOT NULL check (things <> '{}' and array_position(things, null) is null)
);
```

Comment: That's beautiful, and you both guys had the same idea instantly!